# How to run a program as admin

Tags: windows-server-2003, wcf

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_S2

According to this article, Section Scenario 2: Configure an application to always run elevated,

I cannot see "Run this program as an administrator" option and I think the application is blocked from always running elevated.

The original problem was that I need this application to run under a windows account, and automatically being Windows authenticated. The application is currently asking for user-name and pass to access a windows authenticated web service.

The application is a flash application converted someway (to exe app)

1- Is there a way to let it work as administrator?
2- Is there a way to let the application pass the Windows authentication?

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as UAC in Server 2003, which is what that article focuses on. Did you mean to tag as Server 2008?

Comment: no I thought it is Win 2003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, I'd create a scheduled task that runs the app and configure it to run as the local admin (or whatever account is necessary). In your case, however, i don't think that's your problem: the app simply isn't using the security context it's run from when trying to authenticate: that's why it's prompting you.

Answer (score 0):

Try holding down the Shift key, then right click on the .exe, and select Run as...

This should allow you to select an administrative user under which the application should execute.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the flash application relied on the browser to authenticate the user.  I would try logging into the workstation that you want to test this on as the user that should have access.  If it still fails (since you noww are the user trying to authenticate) then the problem isn't that you are not running with the right credentials, the problem is with the application failing to pass them on.

If in fact this succeeds you should then be able to log on with a non administrative account and use the [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) command to launch the application.

Comment: Nop it is Flash desktop application (somehow)

Comment: SWF wrappers can make any flash application run without a browser however I do not know of any way to code a flash application to present windows authentication without a browser (not that I am a coding expert by any means).  This doesn't stop you from attempting to determine whether its the app or the credentials that are failing.